# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration maven error

Tags: maven

i imported an existing maven project but i'm getting some errors in the pom.xml :

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-

 compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (execution: default-compile, phase: compile) pom.xml 

 /org.squashtest.csp.tools.unittest line 50 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```

but i can't understand why ,

Here's the pom.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org  
  /2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   
  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <artifactId>squashtest-csp-tools</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.squashtest.tm</groupId>
    <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>org.squashtest.csp.tools.unittest</artifactId>
<name>Squashtest CSP - Tools module - Unit tests library</name>
<description>Library  of classes used for unit-testing other Squashtest        
     components</description>

<dependencies>
    <!-- ====== GROOVY ====== -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- ====== /GROOVY ====== -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.squashtest.org.hibernate.core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
        <artifactId>unitils-database</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/groovy</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/groovy</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions><execution></execution></executions>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
      </plugin> 
    </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You have typo in the pom with duplicate execution tags.

Answer (score 28):

This is an issue with Groovy maven configuration.  More specifically, m2e connector issues which are, generally speaking, a nightmare. This link contains good info about [the m2e connector mess](http://grumpyapache.blogspot.com/2011/08/mess-that-is-m2e-connectors.html).

### Summary

To fix this, you can grab the m2e connector that springsource provides.

http://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/e4.2/

### Details

To use it:

1. Click Help > Install new software...
2. Paste the URL above in the "Work With:" field
3. Expand "m2e Configurator for Groovy-Eclipse"
4. Choose the first option "Groovy-Eclipse m2e Integration" and install it

[image: Install Groovy-Eclipse M2E Integratoin]

I would also recommend installing the "Groovy/Grails Tool Suite for Eclipse" (GGTS) from the Eclipse Marketplace.  I just did both of these (installing GGTS then the connector) in Eclipse Kepler and it solved the exact issue you had, above.  This fix also works in Juno.

Comment: I think I forget to install this m2e connector every time I install Groovy Eclipse.

Comment: I also had to install the groovy Compiler, then it worked perfectly. ty

Answer (score 0):

In Maven there are few things need to check before this error.

1. Are you able to download the jars from .m2 Repository?
   -> For this Just delete the repository folder under .m2 Folder and try to update the Maven projects. Then you can see the new Repository folder under .m2 folder.
   -> Check all the maven-plugin jars are came under org/apache/maven
2. Check are you able to open the Repository url what ever you mentioned in Settings.xml file
   -> Open ths url in any browser and check whether are you able to open or not.
3. Some times thrid party repository jars might be corrupted.
   -> This will take care by thrid party persons
   -> Ex: if you are pointing to Nexus repository, they have to upload the required maven jars once again. Some times while uploading the jars might be corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to install the M2E Groovy-Eclipse integration but also to add more configuration to the maven compiler plugin in order to work with java and groovy classes:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
       <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
       <source>1.7</source>
           <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.0-01</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.8-01</version>
                </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Eclipse said

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.0.0:checkstyle (execution: default, phase: validate)

After removed checkstyle, there have been other similar problems.

To solve it, I click the quick fixes option: "Discover new m2e connectors". Eclipse list automatically what needed. All you have to do is to click the Finish button.

My Eclipse version is Oxygen.2(4.7.2). Hope this helps.