# Eclipse - Maven project error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I imported a small project with a pom file in Eclipse Kepler.

Now (without me doing anything yet) this project is in red, and I am seeing
these errors shown by Eclipse which I guess means I am missing some Eclipse
plugin related to Maven support.

- *"Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)"*
- *Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)*

I already read here ...

[Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration maven error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448298/plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-maven-error)

... that I can get into some m2e connector mess but I want to avoid this as I don't
have much time to waste on all this, I just have to get some code running with or
without Maven.

Also, I noticed this question above is about 2 years ago. Btw, I tried what it says
but Eclipse didn't allow the installation saying I am having some conflicting
dependencies?! So I decided to ask a new question:

Why am I seeing this error and what's the simplest, and most reliable way to get rid of it?

I have no experience with Maven, I just have a basic idea what it's about.

Answer (score 0):

> Why am I seeing this error and what's the simplest, and most reliable way to get rid of it?

The reason of the error is that eclipse could not find some (compatible) helper plugins for you installation. It should work fine using command line maven (`mvn clean`, `mvn package` ...), but you will have less help from eclipse, the integration might cause more problems than it solves.

Way to get rid of it: find out the details of the original eclipse setup and try to mimic as close as you can. Other IDEs might also be an option.