# m2e cannot transfer metadata from nexus, but maven command line can

Tags: eclipse, maven, nexus, m2e

I'm using nexus to host my maven repository, and maven command line (both win32 and linux) can transfer artifacts from this nexus successfully, using same command and same setting.xml. But m2e will fail as follows:

```
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata m3-app:m3:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to Nexus (http://1.2.3.4:8080/nexus/content/groups/public): Failed to create a selector. to http://1.2.3.4:8080/nexus/content/groups/public/m3-app/m3/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Failure to transfer m3-app:m3:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from http://1.2.3.4:8080/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of Nexus has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata m3-app:m3:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to Nexus (http://1.2.3.4:8080/nexus/content/groups/public): Failed to create a selector. to http://1.2.3.4:8080/nexus/content/groups/public/m3-app/m3/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
```

I've tested the server while eclipse failing to grab artifact, and my browser can get the metadata xml successfully. Is there any problem with m2e?

Update: my project includes about 35 jars, first several jars will succeed, and later it will fail.

Comment: What version of m2e are you using? What version of maven are you using? Does m2e use the same version of maven? Try using the same maven in m2e as you use in command line.

Comment: I'm using maven 3.0.4 and m2e 3.0.4/1.2.0.20120903-0645, which seems the same version

Comment: I would try to use an external maven in m2e. Can you provide the pom of a jar which cannot be transfered? Maybe turn on debug output in m2e to see more logs.

Comment: External maven installation has the same problem. Doing some wireshark, the tcp connection when failing will close rapidly. The artifact cannot be transferred is in fact maven-metadata.xml which contains snapshot version numbers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found: Disable Avira Web guard, and everything looks fine, running in eclipse just as running in command line. Considering change another anti virus solution...