# How to install plugins external through command if that plugins is not available in eclipse market place?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am facing the problem during the plugins of m2eclipse of eclipse.

Jdk -1.6.0(Required)

Eclipse – juno-jee(Required)

After plugins I’m checkout the project as maven then following error is encountered.

1. No marketplace entries found to handle maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information.
2. No marketplace entries found to handle maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information.
3. No marketplace entries found to handle maven-resourse-plugin:2.5:compile in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information.

The process that I have followed to install plugins inside the eclipse.

1. Open Eclipse and click Help > Eclipse Marketplace
2. Search the Marketplace for “Subversive” and choose to Install Subversive – SVN Team Provider
3. Restart Eclipse once this installation has finished.
4. When Eclipse starts again, install the SVN connectors for Subversive. Go to Help > Install New Software and enter http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/4.0/update-site/  into the “Work with:” field
5. Place a checkmark next to: Subversive SVN Connectors and SVNKit 1.8.7 implementation (Checking these two are mandatory).  Feel free to install any other connectors you may need as well.
6. Click Finish to install the SVN connector. This may require another restart of Eclipse.
7. Next, install the Maven2Eclipse plugin: click Help > Install New Software and enter http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases into the “Work with:” field
8. Place a checkmark next to: m2e-Maven Integration for Eclipse and m2e-slf4j over logback logging (select 1.4.0 version as eclipse juno doesnot support 1.5 version).  Feel free to install any other connectors you may need as well.
9. Finally, install Subversive Maven Integration. Go to Help > Install New Software again and enterhttp://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/integrations/update-site/ into the “Work with:” field
10. Place a checkmark next to Subversive Integration for the M2Eclipse Project and click Finish to install it.

Then I add project of SVN Repository Exploring(with url,id,password) and try to

Checkout as maven, and I got above errors.

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried reading your own post?

Comment: try that answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834806/m2eclipse-error