# eclipse - problems with creating maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have tried to create a project with Maven in eclipse with no luck. I have researched and read, then tried the other solutions on other threads but I have no luck.

My settings.xml file is set and is filled out.

Whenever I try to make a maven project i always get this error:

> Could not get the value for parameter encoding for plugin execution
>   default-resources Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to transfer
>   org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.13 from
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
>   Could not transfer artifact
>   org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.13 from/to central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834806/m2eclipse-error

Comment: @harshavmb I can't create the project, so it isn't a duplicate of that one

Answer (score 1):

What solutions have you already tried ?

I had the same problem a few months ago, and it was because I was behind a proxy. 
If it is the same for you, you could look at your web browser configuration.

From the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html) on Configuring a proxy:

```
<proxy>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <host>proxyHost</host>
  <port>proxyPort</port>
  <username>proxyUser</username>
  <password>userPassword</password>
  <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.somewhere.com</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
```

Comment: Do I have to change the proxy settings to my needs or leave it as is?

Comment: If you are behind a proxy,  I mean inside your organization,  you have to give add proxy details in settings.xml and in eclipse as well

Comment: @harshavmb I'm not a company, I'm making a project with a mate. If I don't have a proxy (which I don't), do I change <active>true</active> to <active>false</active>?

Comment: The problem certainly relies elsewhere then... Have you tried mvn clean, or deleting your maven cache ?

Comment: @GuillaumePansier no, I don't think so. How do I?

Comment: you can naviguate to %userprofile%\.m2\repository and delete everything. That is the easiest way.
Afterwards, update the project again.